# Entity Framework Core 3 : Pulling data from multiple sources using join

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I basically have three tables that I need to query information to get PersonNotes. I am using Entity Framwork Core 3.

```
Person Table
PersonNote Table
PersonNoteAttachment Table
```

One person can have many personnotes and one personnote can contain many PersonNoteAttachment.

I need Person table to get the FirstName and LastName which is mapped to the AuthorName in the PersonNote User data model. You can see the mapping section which shows the mapping.

DataModels

```
namespace Genistar.Organisation.Models.DataModels
{

    [Table(nameof(PersonNote), Schema = "common")]
    public class PersonNote
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PersonId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
        public Person Person { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }

        public int AuthorId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("AuthorId")]
        public Person Author { get; set; }

        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public DateTime RecordStartDateTime { get; set; }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public DateTime RecordEndDateTime { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Genistar.Organisation.Models.DataModels
{

    [Table(nameof(PersonNoteAttachment), Schema = "common")]
    public class PersonNoteAttachment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int PersonNoteId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PersonNoteId")]
        public PersonNote PersonNote { get; set; }

        public string Alias { get; set; }

        public string FileName { get; set; }

        public string MimeType { get; set; }

        public int Deleted { get; set; }

        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public DateTime RecordStartDateTime { get; set; }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public DateTime RecordEndDateTime { get; set; }
    }
}
```

User Model - This is the model that I am returning to the client application

```
namespace Genistar.Organisation.Models.User
{
    [Table(nameof(PersonNote), Schema = "common")]
    public class PersonNote
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }
        public string AuthorName { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Mapping

```
CreateMap<Genistar.Organisation.Models.DataModels.PersonNote, Genistar.Organisation.Models.User.PersonNote>()
                  .ForMember(t => t.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
                  .ForMember(t => t.PersonId, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.PersonId))
                  .ForMember(t => t.AuthorName, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Author.FirstName + " " + s.Author.LastName))
                  .ForMember(t => t.Note, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Note))
                  .ForMember(t => t.AuthorId, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.AuthorId))
                  .ForMember(t => t.CreatedBy, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.CreatedBy))
                  .ForMember(t => t.Created, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Created));
```

The following query works but is only pulling data from Person and PersonNote table. I am looking at getting the PersonNoteAttachment as well. How do I do that ? I would basically need  FileName & MimeType 
field populated in User.PersonNote model. If you see above I have created a PersonNoteAttachment data model

Repository

```
public IQueryable<PersonNote> GetPersonNotes(int personId)
        {
            var personNotes = _context.PersonNotes.Include(x => x.Person).Include(x=> x.Author).Where(p => p.PersonId == personId);
            return personNotes;
        }
```

API :

```
 [FunctionName(nameof(GetPersonNote))]
        [UsedImplicitly]
        public Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "person-note/{id}")] HttpRequest req,
            int id) => _helper.HandleAsync(async () =>
        {
            //await _helper.ValidateRequestAsync(req,  SecurityPolicies.ViewNotes);
            var personNotes = await _organisationRepository.GetPersonNotes(id).ProjectTo<PersonNote>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToListAsync();
            return new OkObjectResult(personNotes);
        });
```

My approach was to do it the following way in the repository but I need to return the PersonNote datamodel in the repository. I cannot add those additional fields in the model because it say invalid columns.How do  I approach this ?

```
 var personNotes = _context.PersonNotes
                .Include(x => x.Person)
                .Include(x => x.Author)
                .Where(p => p.PersonId == personId)
                .Join(_context.PersonNotesAttachments, c => c.Id, cm => cm.PersonNoteId, (c, cm) => new
                {    
                     cm.PersonNote.Id,
                     cm.PersonNote.PersonId,
                     cm.PersonNote.Person,
                     cm.PersonNote.Note,
                     cm.FileName,
                     cm.MimeType,
                     cm.Alias,
                     cm.PersonNote.AuthorId,
                     cm.PersonNote.CreatedBy,
                     cm.PersonNote.Created
                });
```

Comment: I tried adding the  public int PersonNoteId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PersonNoteId")]
        public PersonNoteAttachment PersonNoteAttachment { get; set; } in the PersonNote data model but get error invalid column PersonNoteId . I believe this is because the underlying table does not have it. It need not have it. What is the workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue

I just had to add the following line in PersonNote datamodel

```
 public PersonNoteAttachment PersonNoteAttachment { get; set; }
```

Added the new fields to the PersonNote usermodel and did the following mapping

```
 .ForMember(t => t.FileName, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.PersonNoteAttachment.FileName))
                  .ForMember(t => t.MimeType, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.PersonNoteAttachment.MimeType))
                  .ForMember(t => t.Alias, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.PersonNoteAttachment.Alias))
```